# Starting an windows application with different regional settings

Tags: windows-10

Is it possible to change a shortcut target argumments so you can start a windows application with a different regional setting? For example changing the number delimiter from comma to fullstop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the command line parameters for each application differ. Some accept none, some only a target file, usw. It is doubtful any *application* has settings for locale.

That said, you can easily change the locale (international settings) with a Registry script. Run one script before starting the application, and another to revert afterwards. To create the scripts:

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, type *reged*, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select *Regedit*.
- Accept the UAC prompt to run this application.
- In the location bar, enter `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International`, or scroll to that location.

[image: Locale settings]

- Right-click on *International*, select *Export*, and save the .reg file with a name indicating your current locale settings, e.g. portuguese.reg.
- Either use the Windows Control Panel to set the locale (decimal delimiter, date/time format, etc.), or make the changes directly in *Regedit*, if you are confident.
- Press <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh *Regedit*, if you've made changes with the Windows Control Panel.
- Export the settings with an appropriate name, e.g., deutschland.reg.

Now, to change you locale in one keypress or click (well, a few, since you must confirm Registry merges), just run the appropriate script.

BTW, some applications may behave oddly if you change locale while they are running, but you can experiment with changing it "on the fly".

If you want to have a single shortcut that **both** sets locale and then starts the application, create a batch file that runs the .reg script and then starts the application... but you'll still need to confirm the UAC warning for the .reg merger.